# How to achieve unique_wihtout like required_without in Validation of Laravel

Tags: laravel, unique

Here is my code :

```
$this->validate($req, [
  'city' => 'sometimes|unique:regions,city,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
  'province' =>'required_without:city|unique:regions,province,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL,city,NULL',
]);
```

I want

1.province required and unique when city `null`.

2.province should not unique when city `not_null`

3.table name regions

How to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at your table name and columns here, but this should be close:

```
'province' => 'required_without:city|unique:provinces,name',
```

Changes `provinces` to the correct table name and `name` to the column you store them under.

Comment: i did supplement my questions. it do not work when city not_null. thanks an yway.